# How can I fasten the front of a cabinet base securely?

Tags: kitchens

I think the plank needs to be rotated 180deg so its left side goes to the right side for it to be correctly aligned. Anyway, this wooden plank certainly had a plastic clamp (or maybe something else) that made it hold onto one of the pipes seen in the image but it has broken off. This is probably because it was plastic clamp and not metal.

I am a new home owner and I cannot figure out how to put this wooden plank back so it does not flip over to the ground again and expose the mess under the kitchen cabinet. What options do I have?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would install vertical rails to the perpendicular cabinet panels using short screws. These would act as stops and clasp mounts. Then I'd install cabinet catches at each end of the panel.

[image]

```
PLAN (TOP) VIEW

| |         * catch                           | |
| |_                                         _| |
| |_|*_____________________________________*|_| |
|_|___________________________________________| |
                                              | |
                                              | |
                                              | |
```

Comment: I like this idea, +1; alternative to the cabinet catches would be to just screw/nail & glue the panel to the new vertical rails...

Comment: An alternative to cabinet catches would be a pair of magnets which would mate with small steel plates, like those used to keep closet doors closed.

Answer (score 2):

That plank has a metal plate that has the sprung clip missing - this would be clearer if the plank was flipped then that plate would align with one of the legs.

A quality installer would have added an extra leg on the right to hold the plank securely.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that there would be clips to hold it to under sink plumbing because the plumbing is not part of the cabinet and there's no telling where pipes might be.

Much more likely is that it's supposed to be screwed into the left-side wall or that it's supposed to be screwed down through the floor of the cabinet itself.

I'd suggest looking at the ends of the board to see if there are holes for screws, or look at the other long edge (away from camera) for screw holes, as there don't appear to be any on the long edge toward camera.

If you don't find any existing holes, then you can make your own by drilling holes for screws then driving screws into your holes. You *will* want to drill pilot holes as particle board (which this is made of) can easily swell and split from trying to drive a screw into it without a pilot hole.

For the simple purpose of holding this toe kick in place, darn near any screw will do - this isn't a structural piece, it just needs 2 or 3 screws evenly spaced across its length to hold it there. If this were a structural piece, you'd want screws specifically for particle board.

Comment: Actually I realised that those black things are not plimbing, it is leg and feet of the structure above. The people that installed this whole kitchen cabinet system would have drilled in a clamp or something which has broken on that wooden plank now. The plank is actually supposed to be rotated 180 deg so left side goes to right, so that part with 2 screws in the plank aligns with the plastic vertical blank thing in the background.

Comment: Right, what is oddly missing is the leg under the right side of the right cabinet.  Perhaps they screwed it to the wall.  Some toe kick systems(Ikea) would have plastic clips that go around the legs.  I think your system depended on some metal or magnetic clip in the center.